# invalid use of ‘counter::counter’ in c code at line 43

Tags: c++

i am getting error in the following code **invalid use of ‘counter::counter’**

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class counter   
{
protected:
    int value;
public:
    counter ()
    {
        value=0;
    }
    counter (int val)
    {
        value=val;
    }
    int GetCounter()
    {
        return value;
    }
    counter up()
    {
        value=value+1;
    }
};
class NewCounter : public counter   
{
public:
    NewCounter():counter()
    {}
    NewCounter(int val):counter(int val)
    {}
    void Down()
    {
        value=value-1;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    NewCounter con1;
    NewCounter con2;
    con2.counter(1);
    cout<<"Counetr Initially"<<con1.GetCounter()<<endl;
    cout<<"Counter initially"<<con2.GetCounter()<<endl;
    con1.up();
    con2.up();
    cout<<"Counter 1 on incrrr---"<<con1.GetCounter()<<endl;
    cout<<"Counter  2 on incrrr---"<<con2.GetCounter()<<endl;
    con1.Down();
    con2.Down();
    cout<<"count 1 on down"<<con1.GetCounter()<<endl;
    cout<<"count 2 on down"<<con2.GetCounter()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: i was trying to edit the code first..:P

Comment: I removed the `java` tag...

Comment: You can't do this: `con2.counter(1);`. What are you actually trying to do in that line?

Comment: Fix the indentation if you're editing, for crying out loud...

Comment: No C here... Just C++...

Comment: `up` has no return value and this is not correct `NewCounter(int val):counter(int val)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are trying to instantiate a `NewCounter` object and set it's data member to something:

```
NewCounter con2;
con2.counter(1);
```

The second line is illegal, `counter` is a constructor that cannot be called like a member function. But you do this instead:

```
NewCounter con2(1);
```

This will work provided you fix your `NewCounter` constructor:

```
NewCounter(int val):counter(val) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

At line:

```
con2.counter(1);
```

you are calling the constructor of the subobject `counter`. That's silly and illegal. Instead, you can call the `NewCounter(int)` constructor and the `int` will be passed to the `counter` constructor:

```
NewCounter con2(1);
```

Comment: It's not "there's no need"; it's "that's silly and impossible".

Answer (score 1):

```
NewCounter con2;
con2.counter(1);
```

no; `counter` is not a function that you can call!

You pass constructor arguments in one go:

```
NewCounter con2(1);
```